# Getting React Props after sending it from Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I Am Sending React Component from a route as mention in this [Link](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/)

```
<Route path='/StartCompaign' render={(props) => <CampaignStart {...props} isDashboard={true} /> } />
```

and i am getting props in another Component like

```
{props.childern.render.isDashboard ? <Header /> : "NO"  }
```

APP.JSX file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';

import Home from './components/Dynamic/Home';
import Filter from './components/Dynamic/Filter';
import { AboutCampaign } from './components/Dynamic/AboutCampaign';
import { CampaignStart } from './components/Dynamic/CompaignStart';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import {SignUp} from './components/Static/SignUp';  
import { Login } from './components/Static/Login';  

import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard'

import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Layout>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/filter' component={Filter}/>
                    <Route path='/Campaign/:campaignId' component={AboutCampaign}/>
                    <Route path='/SignUp' component={SignUp}/>
                    <Route path='/Login' component={Login}/>
                    <Route path='/Dashboard' render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} isDashboard={true} /> } />

                    <Route path="" component={NotFound} />
                </Layout>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

export default withCookies(App);
```

Layout.JSX

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import Header from './Static/Header';
import Footer from './Static/Footer';
import TopNavigation from './Component/DashBoard/TopNavigation'

export default props => (
    <div>
        {props.isDashboard ? <Header /> : <TopNavigation />  }
        <Container>
            {props.children}
        </Container>
        <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

I am trying to change the `<Header/>` and `<TopNavigation />` in react application when the specfic route is called but `props.isDashboard`  seemed `undefined`

Comment: You're using the props in `Layout` but passing it to `Dashboard`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are sending props to `<Dashboard/>` component

`<Dashboard {...props} isDashboard={true} />`

but not to `<Layout />` component.
If Layout component needs to receive isDashboard props you need to pass it like

`<Layout isDashboard={true} />`

As Layout is parent component, if child components also needs the props you could always pass those to children easily.